# Iterate a numeric vector in a list

Tags: r

I have a list `NList` of numeric vector like

```
[[1]]
[1] 1959 9 4 62

[[2]]
[1] 2280  2  13

[[3]]
[1] 15 4  13

[[4]]
[1] 2902  178   13
```

and the structure is like

```
list(c(1959, 13), c(2280, 178, 13), c(2612, 178, 13), c(2902, 
178, 13), c(2389, 178, 13), c(216, 736, 13), c(2337, 178, 13), 
    c(2639, 2126, 13), c(2924, 676, 178, 13), c(2416, 674, 178, 
    13), c(2223, 13), c(842, 178, 13), c(2618, 1570, 178, 13), 
    c(854, 178, 13), c(1847, 178, 13), c(2529, 178, 13), c(511, 
    178, 13), c(2221, 736, 13), c(415, 674, 178, 13), c(2438, 
    178, 13), c(2127, 178, 13), c(1910, 2126, 13), c(1904, 674, 
    178, 13), c(2310, 674, 178, 13), c(1732, 178, 13), c(1843, 
    178, 13), c(2539, 178, 13), c(1572, 676, 178, 13), c(1616, 
    876, 13).....)
```

I want to iterate the numeric vectors in this list, I would like to do something as:

```
  sum<- 0
  index<-1
  list1 <- apply(NList,1,function (i){
  #I want to get each of the numeric vector here
  row <- NList[i]

  #then I want to iterate the numeric vector for some calculation.
  #I am expecting, for [[1]], I get f(1959,9)+f(9,4)+f(4,62), in which f is my customized function, below I use a simple multiple as example
  for (j in (1:(length(row)-1)))
  {
    origin <- row[j]
    dest <- row[j+1]
    #a simple calculation example...I am expecting an array of sum which is the calculation result 
    sum[index] <- sum[index] + origin*dest
  }
  index <- index+1  

  })
```

but it does not work and returns:

```
dim(X) must have a positive length
```

The lapply is not working for me and return sum as 0...

```
listR1 <- lapply(NList,function (i){
  row <- i
  for (j in 1:length(row))
  {origin <- row[j]
  dest <- row[j+1]
  sum[index] <- sum[index] + origin*dest
  }

  })
```

Did I miss something? How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: It is very confusing to have an object named `list` because `list()` is a function.

Comment: To `apply` over a list you want `?lapply`.  Aside from that, I can't follow your example...

Comment: Can you tell us more about the outcome you're like rather than how to do.  Your approach seems very un-R-like.

Comment: When you get it working, another thing you'll want to look into is your use of `(1:length(row)-1)`. Type `1:5-1` into R and compare this to `1:(5-1)` - I think you'll want brackets around your `length(row)-1`

Comment: Sorry for this newbie question. I tried the lapply but I cannot get the object in a list....I just started programming in R and still confused at its iterator.

Comment: @Tyler Rinker Could you suggest an R-like approach considering this kind of iterator problem? That will be very helpful for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took the function out of your apply statement to look at it a bit closer.

```
    f=function(Row) 
    {
     Sum<- 0
      for (j in 1:(length(Row)-1)  )
      {
            Sum<- j + Row[j]*Row[j+1]
      }
     Sum    # returns the Sum
    }
```

Then I can apply the function to each row with:

```
  list1 <- lapply(NList,f)
```

Comment: Thanks! It really works. I am wondering why my approach does not work. Or could you point me to some materials on vectorization in R?

Comment: My favorite source on vectorizing is http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf circle 3.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so this code would work:

```
f=function(a,b) sum(a,b)

test.func=function (i){
  for (j in 1:(length(i)-1))
    ret.val[j]=f(i[j],i[j+1])  
  ret.val
}

# Use lapply for a list.
lapply(NList,test.func)
```

Or you could do it in one line:

```
lapply(NList,apply(seq_along(i)[-length(i)],function(x) f(i[x],i[x+1])))
```

Comment: It looks very nice too...Thank you very much to your answer.